# Color java code the way it is colored in eclipse

Tags: plugins, syntax-highlighting

There are a lot of plugins that color code. But most java developers work with Eclipse and Eclipse has a very specific way of coloring code.

Is there a plugin that colors code exactly the same way Eclipse does?

Comment: [This SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613453/how-can-i-use-eclipse-code-style-to-highlight-my-code-in-wordpress) is giving some leads.

Comment: I saw this thread before writing my question (I guess I was lazy enough not to include it in the original question)

Comment: Can I upvote comments as in SO? Doesn't seem so.

Comment: **RE:** Comment voting, you just need to gain a little rep before you're able to vote on comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of the Syntax Highlight plugins work in a way that they create divs,spans with classes styled by css and you can simply overwrite that style with your  own css to match the eclipse colors.

### Update

turns out someone has done the job for you, take a look at [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/) which has an eclipse theme.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot upvote you - <15 rep :(

Comment: I need something easy to use, that does not require me to do it by myself - this will not add a lot of value to my posts, so I'm not ready to invest time in it. And I'm lazy :)

Comment: Its Simple CSS that you can do in 5 minutes one time only.

Comment: So why hasn't anyone done it yet?

Comment: Why haven't you done it yet?

Comment: :) As I already said so - I'm lazy. Also, I'm not very good with CSS, I'm bad with colors, I haven't used any photo editing software for quite a while (I guess to extract the colors, or maybe directly from Eclipse), ...

Comment: @Mihail updated my answer for all of the lazy people who use WordPress.

Comment: I'll check it out.

Answer (score -1):

This looks promising:
`http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html`

They don't have java yet, but plan to. Also their coloring scheme looks close to what I want